# Linking against WinNLS

Tags: windows, linkage, nls

What static library should I use to link against to use the [`NormalizeString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319093%28VS.85%29.aspx) function?

In contrast with most functions documented on MSDN, the static library required to use the function is not declared.  I tried using the name derived from the DLL: `normaliz.lib`  and it successfully linked, but then I get a pop-up at runtime saying `Normalization.dll`  could not be found on my computer and the process is shut down.

Comment: It is Normaliz.dll.  Available only in Vista and up.  If you intend to target XP then be sure to set the _WIN32_WINNT macro value properly so you'll get compile errors for functions that are not available in the target operating system.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, I'm already checking ``_WIN32_WINNT``.  I'm testing on Windows 7.

Comment: Works fine when I try this on Windows 7.  What version of the Windows SDK are you using?  I tried it with 6.0, while debugging I see it implemented in kernel32.dll with RtlNormalizeString in ntdll.dll.  Which makes the documentation subtly wrong, normaliz.lib instead of normaliz.dll

Comment: @Hans: I've tried using both Windows SDK v6.0A and v7.0(something) on two Windows 7 machines.  What static library are you linking against?

Comment: Normaliz.lib, it won't link otherwise.  It is not a static lib, it is an import lib.  You need to find out where "normalization.dll" comes from.  Use dumpbin.exe /imports

Comment: @Hans: ran `dumpbin /imports myprogram.exe` and under `Normalization.dll`, only `Ordinal 1` shows up.  Other DLLs, such as `KERNEL32.dll` actually list some known functions, such as `GetLastError()`.

Comment: It is a named export in kernel32.dll, ordinal 881.  The only thing that makes sense is that your linker is picking up a wrong import library.  Add the /VERBOSE option to the linker command line settings to see what .libs it is loading.

Comment: @HansPassant let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2495/discussion-between-andre-caron-and-hans-passant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointer out by Hans Passant, the correct import library is `normaliz.lib`.  It seems there was some problem in my setup.

I was using Windows SDK v6.0A.  After switching to Windows SDK v7.0A, my problems stopped.

Comment: Just had this problem on another computer.  Upgrading to v7.0A fixed the problem there too.

Answer (score 0):

The link at the bottom-ish of the page you linked states that the download contains implib and dll resources. You probably have to manifest the dll, or at least put it into PATH.

Comment: The extra downloads are for Windows XP.  I'm on Windows 7, and it's supposed to be built-in since Windows Vista.

Comment: FYI: The downlaod does not contain import libs (as it seems to have become normal.)